# Outlook 2016 Can No Longer Expand Distribution Group - + Plus Sign Missing - Looks Like Microsoft Recent Update

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, distribution-list

Microsoft, in its infinite wisdom, appears to have removed the plus sign next to Microsoft Office 365 Group email addresses. I have a group called All that has all employees assigned to it. Before this week you could type in all@domain.com in a new email message TO: field, and a plus sign would appear next to it. If clicked it would explode the distribution member email addresses into the TO: field which enabled group owners to remove certain addresses from receiving the email. This is now gone.

When I investigated this there is a new Group Settings under a Group tab in Outlook 2016 that appears when I click on an email in the inbox that was sent to a Group email address. I received a popup saying something to the effect of Check out our new Group Settings!

Does anybody have an answer for restoring this plus sign next to distribution group emails? I don't think there is one but I wanted to check.

I tried adding HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\Outlook\Options\Mail
DWORD: DisableDLExpansion
Value: 0 (1 is to hide the plus sign) but it made no difference.

You used to be able to do these steps below, which is no longer possible:

Expanding a Distribution List
In order to see the members of a distribution list in Outlook, follow these steps:

1. Enter the lists's name into To, Cc, or Bcc field.
2. Click on Check Names icon on the ribbon or press Ctrl + K to validate list's name.
3. Click the plus sign (+) next to the name of the distribution list to show the list members.

Note: When you expand the list, the distribution list name is replaced with all the individual names on the list. You cannot collapse the list again in a message once it's been expanded.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the group name, then changing it back in the Exchange Admin area appeared to be the reason it returned for this user.

The other change I tried but it didn't look like it helped was to create the DisableDLExpansion registry key, then delete it for Outlook 2016.

The DisableDLExpansion registry value is supported in Outlook 2007 and up. To use it in Outlook 2016, add the DisableDLExpansion DWORD to the registry at HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\Outlook\Options\Mail\ and set the value to 1. For the other supported versions, change the version number in the registry path. As with moderated groups, users will be able to open the distribution group and view the members but will not be able to expand the list to bypass list controls.

Outlook 2016

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Options\Mail
HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\Outlook\Options\Mail
DWORD: DisableDLExpansion
Value: 1

Outlook 2013

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Options\Mail
HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\15.0\Outlook\Options\Mail
DWORD: DisableDLExpansion
Value: 1

Outlook 2010

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Options\Mail
HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\14.0\Outlook\Options\Mail
DWORD: DisableDLExpansion
Value: 1

Outlook 2007

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Options\Mail
HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\12.0\Outlook\Options\Mail
DWORD: DisableDLExpansion
Value: 1

Comment: Had the same user experience the loss of the plus sign again, and changing the name of the group then changing it back restored the functionality overnight.

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my latest version of Outlook 365 and found that the + Plus Sign is still available when editing email message. Does this happen to all the groups in your Outlook? As I know, there could be some add-ins in your Outlook client that cause this issue, so it is suggested to start your Outlook in safe mode (Press Win + R, type “outlook /safe”, press Enter.) and see if the issue continues.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for verifying this. I found that renaming the distribution goup then reverting the name seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK
When you click the +, the expanded list you will see are the group members as they were the last time you downloaded a copy of the address book. Therefore:

1. If you don't click the + and just send the email to the group, it will be sent to all members of the group including new members who were added after you last downloaded a copy of the address book.
2. If you do click the + to expand the group and then you click send, it will be sent to only those who were members of the group at the time you last downloaded a copy of the address book (i.e. you might miss new members just added).
   AFAIK

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).